# Filter vertices on several properties - Julia

Tags: graph, filter, julia, vertex

I am working on julia with the `Metagraphs.jl` library.
In order to conduct an optimization problem, I would like to get the set/list of edges in the graph that point to a special set of vertices having 2 particular properties in common.

My first guess was to first get the set/list of vertices. But I am facing a first issue which is that the `filter_vertices` function doesn't seem to accept to apply a filter on more than one property. 
Here is below an example of what I would like to do:

```
g = DiGraph(5)
mg = MetaDiGraph(g, 1.0)

add_vertex!(mg)

add_edge!(mg,1,2)
add_edge!(mg,1,3)
add_edge!(mg,1,4)
add_edge!(mg,2,5)
add_edge!(mg,3,5)
add_edge!(mg,5,6)
add_edge!(mg,4,6)

set_props!(mg,3,Dict(:prop1=>1,:prop2=>2))

set_props!(mg,1,Dict(:prop1=>1,:prop2=>0))
set_props!(mg,2,Dict(:prop1=>1,:prop2=>0))
set_props!(mg,4,Dict(:prop1=>0,:prop2=>2))
set_props!(mg,5,Dict(:prop1=>0,:prop2=>2))
set_props!(mg,6,Dict(:prop1=>0,:prop2=>0))

col=collect(filter_vertices(mg,:prop1,1,:prop2,2))
```

And I want `col` to find vertex 3 and no others.

But the `filter_vertices` would only admit one property at a time and then it makes it more costly to do a loop with 2 filters and then try to compare in order to sort a list with the vertices that have both properties.

Considering the size of my graph I would like to avoid defining this set with multiple and costly loops. Would any one of you have an idea of how to solve this issue in an easy and soft way?

I ended up making this to answer my own question:

```
fil3=Array{Int64,1}()
fil1=filter_vertices(mg,:prop1,1)
for f in fil1
    if get_prop(mg,f,:prop2)==2
        push!(fil3,f)
    end
end            
println(fil3)
```

But tell me if you get anything more interesting

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please consider opening up issues in the LightGraphs / MetaGraphs repos. This way we get notified immediately and can help directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide a minimal working example in a way we can simply copy and paste, and start right away. Please also indicate where the problem occurs in the code. Below is an example for your scenario:

```
Pkg.add("MetaGraphs")

using LightGraphs, MetaGraphs

g = DiGraph(5)
mg = MetaDiGraph(g, 1.0)

add_vertex!(mg)

add_edge!(mg,1,2)
add_edge!(mg,1,3)
add_edge!(mg,1,4)
add_edge!(mg,2,5)
add_edge!(mg,3,5)
add_edge!(mg,5,6)
add_edge!(mg,4,6)

set_props!(mg,3,Dict(:prop1=>1,:prop2=>2))
set_props!(mg,1,Dict(:prop1=>1,:prop2=>0))
set_props!(mg,2,Dict(:prop1=>1,:prop2=>0))
set_props!(mg,4,Dict(:prop1=>0,:prop2=>2))
set_props!(mg,5,Dict(:prop1=>0,:prop2=>2))
set_props!(mg,6,Dict(:prop1=>0,:prop2=>0))

function my_vertex_filter(g::AbstractMetaGraph, v::Integer, prop1, prop2)
  return has_prop(g, v, :prop1) && get_prop(g, v, :prop1) == prop1 &&
         has_prop(g, v, :prop2) && get_prop(g, v, :prop2) == prop2
end

prop1 = 1
prop2 = 2

col = collect(filter_vertices(mg, (g,v)->my_vertex_filter(g,v,prop1,prop2)))
# returns Int[3]
```

Please check `?filter_vertices` --- it gives you a hint on what/how to write to define your custom filter.

**EDIT.** For filtering the edges, you can have a look at `?filter_edges` to see what you need to achieve the edge filtering. Append the below code excerpt to the solution above to get your results:

```
function my_edge_filter(g, e, prop1, prop2)
  v = dst(e) # get the edge's destination vertex
  return my_vertex_filter(g, v, prop1, prop2)
end

myedges = collect(filter_edges(mg, (g,e)->my_edge_filter(g,e,prop1,prop2)))
# returns [Edge 1 => 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works better indeed.
But I have a question concerning the rest of what I intend to do, I would like to get the edges going into these vertices with these special "prop"s and I am using the function in_edges but it seems to return the in vertices. I would like it to return the edges, do you know a simple way to do it?

Comment: @Alexo I have updated my answer. It is hard to understand from your comment, but I think you need something like that. Please, for the next time, write the exact problem you would like to solve. You can update your question above, accordingly.

Comment: Hi @Arda, thank you and yes it was what i needed. The issue concerning my real problem I would like to solve is that:
1. It is quite huge and requires several julia files with several different objects, graphs, variables.
2. The content and the data of the model cannot be putted online.
This is why I tried to explain my problem with a simple model and you got it right. I actually didn't know how to define the function for the input of the filter_edges function. Thank you again.

Comment: @Alexo To be honest, I couldn't do it in the first shot. Maybe we should open a pull request to the documentation of that package. If there were an example regarding this scenario, it would be easier for people like you in the future. I just checked the REPL help, and did some guess work using the exported functions from the package. As per your MWE, in my opinion, it is enough to write your code excerpt with _only_ three `add_edge!` and `set_props!`, and ask the question you asked here in the comments: "How can I filter the edges on two properties? I would like to obtain `1 => 3`."

Comment: yes I couldn't find any explanation on how to define this "fn" function they describe in the Github pages. It is only written that the input should be (g,v). More information for people in the future can only be good. And yes for the in_edges function, it doesn't seem to return edges. However I don't know how to open a pull request or else... I just started julia two months ago.

Comment: The `filter_vertices` function that takes the graph and the vertex is intended to return a boolean if the vertex should be included. See https://juliagraphs.github.io/MetaGraphs.jl/latest/metagraphs.html#MetaGraphs.filter_vertices-Tuple{MetaGraphs.AbstractMetaGraph,Function}: "Return an iterator to all vertices... where function fn returns true only for vertices that should be included in the iterator."

Comment: "If there were an example regarding this scenario, it would be easier for people like you in the future." I agree that the documentation documents it properly. Example would have been nice. I needed to check the [corresponding line](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/MetaGraphs.jl/blob/6fb3813e3953ddb29d637a0b35f47185faf2a63b/src/MetaGraphs.jl#L453) to write the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
function filter_function1(g,prop1,prop2)
  fil1=filter_vertices(g,:prop1,prop1)
  fil2=filter_vertices(g,:prop2,prop2)
  filter=intersect(fil1,fil2)
  return filter
end
```

This seems to work and is quite easy to implement.
Just I don't know if the filter_vertices function is taking a lot of computational power.
Otherwise a simple loop like this seems to also work:

```
function filter_function2(g,prop1,prop2)
  filter=Set{Int64}()
  fil1=filter_vertices(g,:prop1,prop1)
  for f in fil1
      if get_prop(g,f,:prop2)==prop2
          push!(filter,f)
      end
  end
  return filter
end
```

I am open to any other answers if you have some more elegant ones.

Comment: Check my answer. I don't think you should loop through twice --- the package allows you to write a custom filter. Above, `filter_function1` iterates through your graph twice, and calls `intersect`. The complexity is huge. You can make `filter_function2` better with a simple array comprehension.